# Eclipse does not restart in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04  and Eclipse Oxygen 3.A installed on my machine. The Eclipse restart does not work. Eclipse closes but does not start again neither by 'Restart' menu nor if an application requires a restart.

Update: I cleared `.metadata/.log` and then restarted Eclipse from the menu. As usual Eclipse closed down but did not start again. I had to start it by clicking on the icon on my taskbar. Below is the logs generated when I started Eclipse.

```
!SESSION 2018-08-19 20:44:55.135 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2018-08-19 20:45:05.372
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the images from the 'org.eclipse.ui.commandImages' extension point.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2018-08-19 20:45:05.372
!MESSAGE Cannot bind to an undefined command: plug-in='org.eclipse.lsp4e', id='org.eclipse.lsp4e.togglehighlight'

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui 1 0 2018-08-19 20:45:08.115
!MESSAGE A DevStyle Theme is being activated on this workspace; preparing colors and configuration

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.ui 1 0 2018-08-19 20:45:09.652
!MESSAGE DevStyle has archived current color configurations to alternate preferences - will be restored when switching out of the DevStyle Theme

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.patches 2 0 2018-08-19 20:45:13.331
!MESSAGE Patches instrumentation extension PerformanceJavaNavigatorContentProviderPatch ([31078] [Angular] Webclipse UI freezes constantly after closing/reopening Angular 2 projects) has not weaved class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.
```

Comment: Downvoters, please mention why are you downvoting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the path set for `--launcher.library` argument in `eclipse.ini` file was incorrect. I found it out by comparing the ini files from another installation. The path for this argument was set as a relative path which I replaced with an absolute path as below.

```
/home/<username>/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200
```

Comment: Accepted my own answer so that it does not appear as unanswered.